# Draw stacked chart using dygraph

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I want to draw a stacked chart using the [dygraphs](http://dygraphs.com/) JavaScript library, which I've done below. But I want a different color for each bar line. Two colors like bar top section in dark and bottom section in same light color, something like this:

[image]

Please suggest how I can pass a different color for dygraph.
Here's what I have so far:

```js
function barChartPlotter(e) {
  var ctx = e.drawingContext;
  var points = e.points;
  var y_bottom = e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(0); // see <a href="http://dygraphs.com/jsdoc/symbols/Dygraph.html#toDomYCoord">jsdoc</a>

  // This should really be based on the minimum gap
  var bar_width = 2 / 3 * (points[1].canvasx - points[0].canvasx);
  ctx.fillStyle = e.color; // a lighter shade might be more aesthetically pleasing

  // Do the actual plotting.
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var p = points[i];
    var center_x = p.canvasx; // center of the bar

    ctx.fillRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy, bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
    ctx.strokeRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy, bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
  }
}

g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
  "X,Y\n" +
  "1,2\n" +
  "2,4\n" +
  "3,6\n" +
  "4,8\n" +
  "5,10\n" +
  "6,12\n" +
  "7,14\n" +
  "8,16\n", {
    // options go here. See http://dygraphs.com/options.html
    legend: 'always',
    animatedZooms: true,
    plotter: barChartPlotter,
    dateWindow: [0, 9]
  });
```

```css
/*
Relevant CSS classes include:

Labels on the X & Y axes:
.dygraph-axis-label
.dygraph-axis-label-x
.dygraph-axis-label-y
.dygraph-axis-label-y2

Chart labels, see http://dygraphs.com/tests/styled-chart-labels.html
.dygraph-title
.dygraph-xlabel
.dygraph-ylabel
.dygraph-y2label

The legend, see http://dygraphs.com/tests/series-highlight.html
.dygraph-legend
*/

.dygraph-title {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools-core-full-compat.min.js"></script>
<script src="//dygraphs.com/dygraph-dev.js"></script>
<!-- You may set style: "width: ...; height: ..." to size the chart -->
<div id="graph"></div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eM2Mg/132/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code for adding different colors :

```
<div id="graph"></div>

function barChartPlotter(e) {
var myColor = ["#ECD078", "#D95B43", "#C02942", "#542437", "#53777A", "#42d7f4", "red", "green"];
var ctx = e.drawingContext;
var points = e.points;
var y_bottom = e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(0); 

// This should really be based on the minimum gap
var bar_width = 2 / 3 * (points[1].canvasx - points[0].canvasx);
// a lighter shade might be more aesthetically pleasing

// Do the actual plotting.
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    var p = points[i];
    var center_x = p.canvasx; // center of the bar
    ctx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
    ctx.fillRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy, bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
    ctx.strokeRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy, bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
}}
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
"X,Y\n" +
"1,2\n" +
"2,4\n" +
"3,6\n" +
"4,8\n" +
"5,10\n" +
"6,12\n" +
"7,14\n" +
"8,16\n", {
    // options go here. See http://dygraphs.com/options.html
    legend: 'always',
    animatedZooms: true,
    plotter: barChartPlotter,
    dateWindow: [0, 9]
});
```

Comment: Hi Anil Samal  - thanks this looks great; can we have two color in one bar. like in first bar you have added yellow color; but what i was actually looking is half will be dark yellow and half will be light yellow if is there any way to do that that will be great help to me. thanks

Comment: Yes we can have two color's in one bar.Let me Post the code.

Comment: Hi Paresh, Please find the below codewhich will give two different colors for the same bar.

Comment: hi Anil - sorry did not find the code. can you please post is again

Comment: You Need to select colors Which you want to use

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code for adding tow different colors for same Bar:

```
<div id="graph"></div>
    function barChartPlotter(e) {
    var myColor = ["#ECD078", "#D95B43", "#C02942", "#542437", "#53777A", "#42d7f4", "red", "green"];
    var myColor1 = ["black", "red", "green", "#ECD078", "#D95B43", "#C02942", "#542437", "#53777A"];
    var ctx = e.drawingContext;
    var points = e.points;
    var y_bottom = e.dygraph.toDomYCoord(0);

    // This should really be based on the minimum gap
    var bar_width = 2 / 3 * (points[1].canvasx - points[0].canvasx);
    // a lighter shade might be more aesthetically pleasing

    // Do the actual plotting.
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var p = points[i];
        var center_x = p.canvasx; // center of the bar
        ctx.fillStyle = myColor[i];
        ctx.fillRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy, bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
        ctx.strokeRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy, bar_width, y_bottom - p.canvasy);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        var p = points[i];
        console.log(points[1]);
        var center_x = p.canvasx; // center of the bar
        ctx.fillStyle = myColor1[i];
        ctx.fillRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy, bar_width, (y_bottom - p.canvasy) / 2);
        ctx.strokeRect(center_x - bar_width / 2, p.canvasy, bar_width, (y_bottom - p.canvasy) / 2);
    }
}
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graph"),
    "X,Y\n" +
    "1,2\n" +
    "2,4\n" +
    "3,6\n" +
    "4,8\n" +
    "5,10\n" +
    "6,12\n" +
    "7,14\n" +
    "8,16\n", {
        // options go here. See http://dygraphs.com/options.html
        legend: 'always',
        animatedZooms: true,
        plotter: barChartPlotter,
        dateWindow: [0, 9]
    });
```